# Ordering Outlook COM add-ins

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

There are multiple VSTO add-ins installed on a machine. What is the best way of ordering these add-ins such that add-ins common events are also fired up in the same order?

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the addins are loaded is undetermined. Ditto for the COM events order.

Comment: is there any Microsoft KB to support this statement.

Comment: I am not aware of one. Trust me, this is true - it's been the case ever since Outlook 97 was released (which only supported Exchange Client Extensions).